# Sort Date Names Accurately by Partition

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2017

I have the following data:

```
with cte (id,[months]) as (
select  1,  'July 2019'         union all
select  2,  'July 2019'         union all
select  3,  'July 2019'         union all
select  4,  'July 2019'         union all
select  5,  'August 2019'       union all
select  6,  'August 2019'       union all
select  7,  'September 2019'    union all
select  8,  'October 2019'      union all
select  9,  'November 2019'     union all
select  10, 'December 2019'     union all
select  11, 'January 2020'      union all
select  12, 'January 2020'      union all
select  13, 'January 2020'      union all
select  14, 'January 2020'      union all
select  15, 'February 2020'     union all
select  16, 'March 2020'        union all
select  17, 'March 2020'        union all
select  18, 'April 2020'        union all
select  19, 'May 2020'          union all
select  20, 'June 2020'
)
```

I require to create a Sort Column that ranks all the same `months` with the same number.

The problem I experienced with the following code is, it does not sort correctly and also does not provide me with the expected results:

```
select
*
,   dense_rank() over (partition by months order by id) Sort
from    cte
```

Current Results:

[image: Incorrect Results]

My expected results:

[image: Expected Results]

How should I change my script to achieve this?

Comment: If you have any ability to influence the data model, you should suggest changing it. That's a horrible way to store any date related data that anyone expects to be useful as a date.

Comment: Noted thank you @EricBrandt.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a lot of struggle, I managed to resolve this with this script:

```
select
*
,   convert(date,'01 '+Months)                              MonthsConvertedToDate
,   dense_rank() over (order by convert(date,'01 '+Months)) Sort
from    cte
order by sort,id
```

Results:

[image: Expected Results]

See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=04b25f115f177d78b2f9591b3d5a0261)

I am however open to better suggestions :-)